# VBA Date stored as Time instead of MM/DD/YY

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a userform that outputs the user entries to a range on a designated sheet when submitted. From there, a subprocedure encapsulates these different inputs into public variables to be used later.

Some of the user inputs from the userform are dates entered in the following format; MM/DD/YY.
When the sub procedure that assignt the variables from these entries (Ex: DIM var as DATE), instead of saving a date entry such as 01/21/2020 as just a date, it saves it as #12:00:00AM# when stepping through the code.

How can I save these date inputs as a date instead of reverting to a time?

Example Code:

```
Dim job_start as Date

job_start = thisworkbook.worksheets("Variables").cells(1,1).value
```

Where thisworkbook.worksheets("Variables").cells(1,1).value looks like: **11/01/2020**
in the cell.

but if I print job_start into any other cell it prints: **12:00:00 AM**

This happens for all date variables.

Anyway to fix this?

Comment: it Shows this: 12:00:00AM

Comment: CDate(thisworkbook.worksheets("Variables").cells(1,1).value)

Comment: That worked. Perfect, thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
Dim job_start as Date

job_start = CDate(thisworkbook.worksheets("Variables").cells(1,1).value)
```